# Package ‘neuralnet’ in R, rectified linear unit (ReLU) activation function?

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying to use activation functions other than the pre-implemented "logistic" and "tanh" in the R package neuralnet. Specifically, I would like to use rectified linear units (ReLU) f(x) = max{x,0}. Please see my code below.

I believe I can use custom functions if defined by (for example)

```
custom <- function(a) {x*2}
```

but if I set max(x,0) instead of x*2 then R tells me that 'max is not in the derivatives table', and same for '>' operator. So I am looking for a sensible workaround as I am thinking numerical integration of max in this case wouldn't be an issue.

```
nn <- neuralnet(
  as.formula(paste("X",paste(names(Z[,2:10]), collapse="+"),sep="~")),
  data=Z[,1:10], hidden=5, err.fct="sse",
  act.fct="logistic", rep=1,
  linear.output=TRUE)
```

Any ideas? I am a bit confused as I didn't think the `neuralnet` package would do analytical differentiation.

Comment: If you question has been answered, please select the best for you so the question can be marked as closed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The internals of the `neuralnet` package will try to differentiate any function provided to `act.fct`.  You can see the source code [here](https://github.com/cran/neuralnet/blob/master/R/neuralnet.r).

At line 211 you will find the following code block:

```
if (is.function(act.fct)) {
    act.deriv.fct <- differentiate(act.fct)
    attr(act.fct, "type") <- "function"
}
```

The `differentiate` function is a more complex use of the `deriv` function which you can also see in the source code above.  Therefore, it is currently not possible to provide `max(0,x)` to the `act.fct`.  It would require an exception placed in the code to recognize the ReLU and *know* the derivative.  It would be a great exercise to get the source code, add this in and submit to the maintainers to expand (but that may be a bit much).

**However, regarding a sensible workaround,** you could use [softplus function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)) which is a smooth approximation of the ReLU.  Your custom function would look like this:

```
custom <- function(x) {log(1+exp(x))}
```

You can view this approximation in R as well:

```
softplus <- function(x) log(1+exp(x))
relu <- function(x) sapply(x, function(z) max(0,z))

x <- seq(from=-5, to=5, by=0.1)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

fits <- data.frame(x=x, softplus = softplus(x), relu = relu(x))
long <- melt(fits, id.vars="x")
ggplot(data=long, aes(x=x, y=value, group=variable, colour=variable))+
  geom_line(size=1) +
  ggtitle("ReLU & Softplus") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 26)) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 18))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation why and where the problem arises (makes sense now), and thanks also for the workaround (complete with graph!). Will see if I manage to adjust the source code and to know the derivative, but in the meantime workaround runs like a dream. Thanks! A

Comment: @AJGronevelt, glad it works.  If you do modify the source, please do try to submit to the maintainers.  ReLU would be great to have easy access to.  If this fully satisfies your question, please be sure to accept so the question is closed.

Answer (score 5):

You can approximate the max function with a differentiable function, such as:

```
custom <- function(x) {x/(1+exp(-2*k*x))}
```

The variable k determines the accuracy of the approximation.

Other approximations can be derived from equations in section "Analytic approximations": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function

Comment: Thanks for this, works very well, and accuracy control via k works nicely too. A

Answer (score 2):

a bit belated, but in case anyone else is still looking for an answer. Here's how to incorporate the non-approximated ReLu function. This is achieved by loading it from a package.

Note that while you could technically define the relu function yourself (with max() or if(x<0) etc.), this wouldn't work in the neural net package because it needs a differentiable function.

First, load the relu function from sigmoid package, which is differentiable

```
install.packages('sigmoid')
    library(sigmoid)
    relu()
```

Second, insert in your code

```
   nn <- neuralnet(
   as.formula(paste("X",paste(names(Z[,2:10]), collapse="+"),sep="~")),
   data=Z[,1:10], 
   hidden=5, err.fct="sse",
   act.fct=relu,
   rep=1,
   linear.output=TRUE)
```

I found this solution in another post, but can't for the life of me rememeber which one, so credits to unknown.