# Custom error function for neural network in R

Tags: r, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I use R-packages (nnet, amore, neuralnet) for designing a neural network. The problem is that I want to use a custom error function. Based on the output from the neural network I have a custom calculation...

It seems not possible to do this is in a package in R? Is there anybody who knows what I can do?

Other possibility is that I use a genetic algorithm to optimize my weights of my neural network, but I don't get the desired optimization here. My network 28 inputs & 9 hidden neurons is too big to use a genetic algorithm to optimize, I get stuck in local optima...
(Maybe the genetic algorithm approach is an option but it would be time consuming to try to achieve a decent solution with it.)

Answer (score 0):

With the `neuralnet` package you can pass custom activation and error functions which are automatically differentiated (assuming the function can be with the internal R functions).  See this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532878/package-neuralnet-in-r-rectified-linear-unit-relu-activation-function/34533294#34533294) regarding how to implemented ReLU for the activation function.  The same thing should be possible by passing your custom error function to the `err.fct` argument.